# Adding new lists within app inventor app

Tags: android, list, app-inventor

I'm having a bit of awkwardness in App Inventor and lists.
I had hoped to generate a list for a user entered value.
For eample - a text box the user enters Book title, publication year, author, and ISBN.
I would like to create a list with the ISBN as list number.

How feasible/practical is this?

Add items x,y,z to (previously non-existent) ISBN list does not work.

I'm currently trying a working around with empty lists List1, List2, etc that are filled sequentlially but this is less than ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very feasible/practical. You have to use 2 lists: listISBN which stores your ISBN and another list, let's call it listDetails which stores sublists of the detail data.
 To save the data, use two [add items to list](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/content/list-blocks.html#add%20items%20to%20list) blocks, see screenshot: [image: screenshot]

To select the items from your lists, use the same list index together with [select list item](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/content/list-blocks.html#select%20list%20item) blocks.[image: screenshot]

More about lists [here](https://sites.google.com/site/blocks123/lists), also see [chapter 19 here](https://sites.google.com/site/appinventor/projects)

Comment: Very nice. I stumbled around and came up with something similar - but not nearly as straightforward and clear. Thank you very much.