# App Inventor - create and display a list of objects

Tags: android, app-inventor

I've searched over the net for this but can't find a solution so decided to post a question here.

I would like to display a list of objects in App Inventor.

Field of the class difining the object would be for example:

text content
number estimatedLength
number importance

How can I store a list of objects described above? I only found examples of separate lists for each field, but is it possible to store them as a list of lists? Does it make sense to store them as a list of lists?

Second question: I would like to display a list of objects, each row would contain an object, and columns would display the fields. Is it doable in App Inventor? I it is, how this can be done?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I store a list of objects described above? I only found examples of separate lists for each field, but is it possible to store them as a list of lists?

yes, you can store them as list of lists, see [here](https://sites.google.com/site/blocks123/lists) for examples about list of lists...

> Does it make sense to store them as a list of lists?

yes of course

> I would like to display a list of objects, each row
>   would contain an object, and columns would display the fields. Is it
>   doable in App Inventor?

you can use 2 lists: a list to store your objects and another list, which is a list of lists, to store the fields, see also [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12552831/1545993) ...

Comment: Thank you! Those examples are useful, but still cannot find a way to dynamically generate rows containing i.e. label (content), label (estimatedLength), label (importance), button (i.e. edit). All I want to achieve is a basic CRUD functionality. All examples I saw were about static User Interface.

Comment: Are you talking about generating App Inventor components like labels, buttons etc. dynamically? This is not possible, see also [issue 197](http://code.google.com/p/app-inventor-for-android/issues/detail?id=197). You only can store data in your list or list of lists. But you can use the advanced features, see [examples here](http://puravidaapps.com/checkbox.php) and more snippets with App Inventor you can find on my [webpage](http://puravidaapps.com/snippets.php)